# Number of swaps with bubble sort for an array is the same as number of individual shifts with insertion sort

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I tried placing counters for bubble sort here -

```
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)         
   for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
       if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
          swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
          printf("%d of %d\n", i, n);
          count++; // here
       }
```

and for insertion sort here -

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) { 
    key = arr[i]; 
    j = i-1; 
    while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) { 
        arr[j+1] = arr[j]; 
        j = j-1; 
        count++;
    } 
    arr[j+1] = key;
}
```

and tried input arrays of various sizes ranging 10, 20, 50, 1000, etc.
but in all cases the number of swaps with bubble sort for an array was **the same** as number of individual shifts with insertion sort. Can someone explain this? My central confusion lies at how the number of *swaps* is same as the number of *shifts*, as they are totally different mechanisms of moving elements within the array.

Comment: Are you sure you implemented the two sorts correctly?

Comment: @Lasse yes, i am sure. i had also used directly copied code from legitimate websites in order to make sure.

Comment: I think the cost issue in sorting is the comparison, not the swapping, so although the exact same number of items were swapped around, bubble sort will compare a lot more items to do that job, in a test program I tried, with 1000 numbers randomized from 0-1000, bubblesort did 934.065 comparisons, whereas insertion sort did 248.631 comparisons. They did the same number of swaps though.

Comment: So you are confirming that it's completely normal behavior for them have the same number of swaps? That is good enough for me. I also ran down an analysis by comparing the algorithms, and yes, it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every shift in insertion sort corrects exactly one **inversion**

Every swap in bubble sort corrects exactly one inversion.

So for the same source data inversion count is similar and numbers of swaps and shifts are equal.

Both algoritms eliminate inversions one-by-one, step-by-step. 
Note that selection sort, for example, uses another strategy: it eliminates all inversions for the smallest element, but might create new inversions for exchanged element, then eliminates all inversions for the second smallest and so on.

---

In general insertion sort works faster because shifts are more effective, make less element moves.

Also average number of comparisons of insertion sort is about `n^/4` for random values (`n^2/2` in the worst case) ([Sedgewick book](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/)) while bubble sort performs `~n^2/2` comparisons (if early stop is not used)

Comment: This answers the stated question, but not the question you can get by reading between the lines. If they both do the same thing (I know, I know), why is insertion sort generally better than bubble sort? (I know the answer)

Comment: Okay, I don't think I know the exact answer you say you know, so tell me anyway, because that's exactly what I need; a specific sentence of answer!

Comment: @Rajdeep Biswas Is your question for me?

Comment: No, sorry it was for @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: No, my comment was for MBo. He answers what you asked, but I feel you (Rajdeep) is asking a bigger question. Apologies if that was wrong.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen no that assumption was absolutely correct. In fact I wanted to know your point of view for the bigger question I was asking; why is insertion sort generally better than bubble sort?

Comment: Because it does fewer comparisons, in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Both the sorting i.e Insertion and Bubble sorting will give the same number of inversions for the same case. The difference between insertion and bubble sorting is the number of iterations in which they sort the case.
Insertion sort takes only one iteration as it compares in both front and backward direction whereas the bubble sort only moves in forward direction and compares the two elements. After each iteration in bubble sort, the largest element in the array is bubbled up the last position.